# Where and how to add a Bearer Token to upload an image to ASP.NET?

Tags: java, android, asp.net, http-post, bearer-token

I've followed [this Github page](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android) and I've encouter problems with Bearer Token Authentication/Authorization in [this class](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/blob/master/HttpTestClient/src/com/survivingwithandroid/HttpClient.java). [In this class](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/blob/master/HttpTestClient/src/com/survivingwithandroid/UploadActivity.java) the file (photo) is being uploaded.

Overhere I've send a POST request to the server (running in Docker), which is deliverd. The server returns a 4XX error, because the authentication isn't working (yet).

See here (POST with phone in Android):
[image]

In this part of code I try to add the Bearer Token:

```
 public void connectForMultipart() throws Exception {
    con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer hereIsMyBearerToken.SomeTextAnd.SomeRandomNumbers132");
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.connect();
    os = con.getOutputStream();
}
```

Following to multiple sources the part `con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer TOKENEHERE")` should work.

In Postman it's working fine, so my token is right.
See here (POST with Postman to test):
[image]

Docker also sends 201 (OK) back:
[image]

I've also tried to authorized in the `UploadActivity` on the Github linked above. Without success.
See here what I've tried in the `SendHttpRequestTask` class in the `UploadActivity`:

```
private class SendHttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        //String param1 = params[1];
        //String param2 = params[2];
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(UploadActivity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.c10);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, baos);

        try {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(url);
            client.connectForMultipart();
            //client.addFormPart("param1", param1);
            //client.addFormPart("param2", param2);
            client.addFilePart("photo", "logo.png", baos.toByteArray());
            client.addFormPart("Bearer hereIsMyBearerToken.SomeTextAnd.SomeRandomNumbers132");
            client.finishMultipart();
            String data = client.getResponse();
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

So where and how should I authorize my POST request?

Comment: What you want to add (bearer token) is not sent as a form part (i.e. part of the request body), it's a HTTP header. Find out how to add headers using the HttpClient class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the token as part of your `Authorization` http header. Additionally I'm not sure if you need to b64 encode the token or not but that could be a secondary issue.